# Regex in Django for configuring url patterns

Tags: python, regex, django

I'm making a browsable directory structure in Django, and I have made it using button forms and `GET` requests, however, I'm trying to achieve the same using links instead of buttons, and I'm confused with *regex*, infact I do not know a thing about it. I tried some stuff and other related answers from SO, but no avail.

Here is my url pattern *(for the one working using buttons and I'd like to make it work with links as well)*:

```
url(r'^realTime/', views.view_real_time_index, name='view_real_time_index'),
```

What I want is to extract the path following the `realTime/` in the suffix from the url.
And this is the template snippet I'm trying to work with:

```
{% for name,path in directory %}
    <li>
        <p>
            <a href='/realTime/{{path}}'> {{name}} </a>
        </p>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `r'realTime/(?P<path>.*)$'` should be fine to begin with.

Comment: @RohitJain Thank you, it worked, I was sure the regex must be having some symbols after <path> but wasn't able to figure out which ones.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the `path` named capture group in your regex in order to be able to use `{{path}}` later. To match anything after `realTime/` you only need `.*`,  you do not even need to define `$`:

```
url(r'^realTime/(?P<path>.*)', views.view_real_time_index, name='view_real_time_index'),
                ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or, if there must be at least 1 character in the path, replace `*` with `+`:

```
url(r'^realTime/(?P<path>.+)', views.view_real_time_index, name='view_real_time_index'),
                         ^^
```

Comment: I'm using the `realTime/` as a **Home Page** where it lists all the drive letters and other shortcut paths. Thank you for the additional information, I'll certainly keep that in mind. I'm actually using the `path` as an argument for the view which further processes the variable and returns the render for a new dictionary according to the path in `path`.

Answer (score 0):

In your urls.py use the following code

```
url(r'^realTime/(?P<path>.*)', views.view_real_time_index, name='view_real_time_index'),
```

And in your views.py you can retrieve and use "path" as:

```
def view_real_time_index(request, path) :
    print(path)
   #your code
```